# Call a function from another thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a script with 2 threads, a basic example is shown below:

```
Thread 1:
    value = stuff()
    if value > 0:
        # Code to make something() run

Thread 2:
    def something():
        # Thread specific task goes here
```

I need something() to be run in Thread 2, not Thread 1. I know how to 'sync' variables with Queue and I know I could just put a loop in Thread 2 that waits for a condition then executes something(), but that would break other stuff in Thread 2.

Sorry if I haven't made this clear, it's kind of hard to explain. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thread 2 needs to have a queue for delayed applications then thread 1 can simply add its call to this queue.

The contents of the queue would be either the name of or a reference to the function and the args and kwargs for use in calling the function.

In the end you would end up using the active object pattern and the promise pattern if you asynchronously wait where the promise has an event. If you wait synchronusly you would most likely lock the called thread and then pass the message and then block on the event and then the called thread would set the event and you would unblock and read the result.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand any of that. Are there any other resources I could look at to help understand that process?